# Hybris production support activities

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am pretty new to Hybris. I am a bit curious about the activities that are taken care of by the production support team in Hybris. please share the information about what are the activities generally a production support person take care.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can give you some idea:

- Study guide for SAP Certified Support Specialist - SAP Commerce 1811: https://cxwiki.sap.com/display/education/Study+guide+for+SAP+Certified+Support+Specialist+-+SAP+Commerce+1811

I think the scope can be quite big, and it will depend on your contract / agreement. It could cover things like:

- Handling day-to-day operations (e.g. backups)
- Managing releases or patches
- Managing users (e.g. Creating/Updating accounts manually)
- Operating Backoffice (e.g. Reloading the widgets, etc) or PCM
- Monitoring the system (e.g. Using DynaTrace)
- Fixing performance issues
- Fixing synchronization issues
- Setting up the infrastructure (e.g. clustering, caching, logging, etc)
- Being familiar with integration with other services (e.g. Data Hub)
- Knowing how to indetify and fix issues / problems in general
- etc